# how to copy all csv files from different source folders into target as per source folders using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I have code as below to copy all *.csv files from different source folders, but i want to copy in different folders as per source, i could able to copy all csv files to single folder but i want it into different folders as source folders.

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

dir = 'C:\\data\\projects\\'
patterns = ['project1','project2']
dest = 'D:\\data\\projects\\'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):

    for pattern in patterns:

        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.csv'):
            source = (os.path.join(root, filename))
            print(source)
            shutil.copy(source, dest)
```

Comment: instead of passing `dest` in the `copy()` method pass the desired location?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os.path.relpath` to extract the subpath for a general method, and `os.makedirs` to create missing directories on the destination:

```
    ...
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.csv'):
        source = (os.path.join(root, filename))
        print(source)
        rel = os.path.relpath(root, dir)
        curdest = os.path.join(dest, rel)
        if not os.path.exists(curdest):
            os.makedirs(curdest, exist_ok=True)
        shutil.copy(source, curdest)
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, appreciate your help.

Comment: Can we skip one of sub-folder  in         curdest = os.path.join(dest, rel)
 we want to ignore one out folder and copy files as per source but ignoring last folder.